# Trying to create this shape and animate the red in css and html alone

Tags: html, css

[image: This is what I wanted to create]

```
.reddiv {
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.reddiv::after {
    content:"\2193";   /* The code for the arrow : see the reference */
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 40px; /* Adjust for your needs */
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is the plnk url 
http://plnkr.co/edit/lSh4cGgT4lRorQd4Lg6s?p=preview

I am unable to understand on how to proceed further

Comment: update your plunker please and put div in side body tag.

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: you need to look keyFrame animation in Css3 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Check this and move further. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086755/css-animation-rotate-on-return/34087395#34087395

Comment: Sorry guys, Ijust didn't update the plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Use it in a single animation and use transform rotate.

```
@keyframes slidedown {
 0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  30%{
     margin-top: 300px;
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100%{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
}
```

Here is a the forked [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WaGoo1m9dpGAVSfcC9BR?p=preview)

Comment: I have created this
http://plnkr.co/edit/lSh4cGgT4lRorQd4Lg6s?p=preview

How ever, I am unable to generate the axis as shown in the image